# Samza Failed to send message. Exception

Tags: exception, apache-samza

I'm using samza on aws emr instances, and I always have exception like follows, can anyone help me?:

org.apache.samza.SamzaException: Failed to send message. Exception:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send after the producer is closed.
    at org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemProducer$$anonfun$send$5.apply(KafkaSystemProducer.scala:120)
    at org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemProducer$$anonfun$send$5.apply(KafkaSystemProducer.scala:111)
    at org.apache.samza.util.ExponentialSleepStrategy.run(ExponentialSleepStrategy.scala:81)
    at org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemProducer.send(KafkaSystemProducer.scala:86)
    at org.apache.samza.system.SystemProducers.send(SystemProducers.scala:87)
    at org.apache.samza.task.TaskInstanceCollector.send(TaskInstanceCollector.scala:61)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.LoggedStore.putAll(LoggedStore.scala:72)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.SerializedKeyValueStore.putAll(SerializedKeyValueStore.scala:57)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.CachedStore.flush(CachedStore.scala:166)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.NullSafeKeyValueStore.flush(NullSafeKeyValueStore.scala:69)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.KeyValueStorageEngine.flush(KeyValueStorageEngine.scala:113)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.KeyValueStorageEngine.close(KeyValueStorageEngine.scala:125)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.kv.KeyValueStorageEngine.stop(KeyValueStorageEngine.scala:119)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.TaskStorageManager$$anonfun$stop$2.apply(TaskStorageManager.scala:147)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.TaskStorageManager$$anonfun$stop$2.apply(TaskStorageManager.scala:147)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
    at org.apache.samza.storage.TaskStorageManager.stop(TaskStorageManager.scala:147)
    at org.apache.samza.container.TaskInstance.shutdownStores(TaskInstance.scala:185)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer$$anonfun$shutdownStores$2.apply(SamzaContainer.scala:650)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer$$anonfun$shutdownStores$2.apply(SamzaContainer.scala:650)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer.shutdownStores(SamzaContainer.scala:650)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer.run(SamzaContainer.scala:560)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer$.safeMain(SamzaContainer.scala:93)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer$.main(SamzaContainer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.samza.container.SamzaContainer.main(SamzaContainer.scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the real exception in the wrong file.

Comment: In case you solved your problem, and in a way that is unlikely to help future readers, you have to option to delete your question (you probably have to unaccept your answer for that). This helps keep the site clean. This is no obligation, you are free to keep it around, I just wanted to let you know of this option:)